# npm build build vue via express build, but index.html does not work

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

**frontend/config/index.js**

```
  build: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../backend/public/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../backend/public'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
  }
```

**backend/app.js**

```
...
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());
...
app.use('/', root);
```

**backend/routes/root.js**

```
  const express = require('express');
  const path = require('path');
  const router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'))
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

I created a public folder on the backend via npm run build.

And I run the express server through node app.js, but I can not access index.html nor any vue components.

When connecting with localhost: // 3000, I get `Cannot GET /` instead of index.html.

What's wrong with me?